# Date Construction in Oracle Server "Oracle database error 1839"

Tags: sql, oracle, tableau-api

Apologies, I am quite new to Oracle SQL so there is probably something blindingly wrong with this!

When I run the below statement as part of a query the following error is given:
"Oracle database error 1839: ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified"

I think this has something to do with leap years, as when I filter my time series for recent data (March-current date) then no error is given

Thanks in advance

```
(TO_CHAR(extract(year from TO_DATE('01/01/2000','DD/MM/YYYY')), '9999') 
- 
(
TO_CHAR(extract(year from "DELIVERY_DATE"), '9999') 
- TO_CHAR(extract(year from "TRADING_DATE"), '9999')
)
)

|| TO_CHAR(extract(month from "TRADING_DATE"), 'FM00') 
|| TO_CHAR(extract(day from "TRADING_DATE"), '99')

,'YYYYMMDD')
```

Comment: Youre correct. The year part maybe 1999 or 1998 depending on the difference between delivery and trading date. So if the month part is feb and day part is 29; you will get an error.  You need to check first the year part is leap year before doing the rest of your SQL. Here is the function to check leap year: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_detect_leap_year_function.htm

Comment: There are several things wrong with this code. For example, you call `TO_CHAR`, which outputs character strings. Then you subtract one string from another. Oracle is tolerant - it will convert the strings back to numbers - and with some luck Oracle will get it right (however, sometimes it does get it wrong). Rather than fix your code, you may get better help if you would explain what problem you were trying to solve in the first place; I am just guessing that a much simpler solution may exist.

Comment: @mathguy, yes we can improve the sql because what it does is copy the month and day from trading date then subtract from year 2000, the difference of the year between delivery date and trade date. Hope it is clear.

Comment: The expression `TO_CHAR(extract(year from TO_DATE('01/01/2000','DD/MM/YYYY')), '9999') ` can be replaced with a simple `'2000'`

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Please [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to add (or subtract) some number of years to the trading date. Its much better to perform arithmetic on dates than to convert them back and forth to strings. From Tableau, you can just used the dateadd() function to say, add N years to a date, and Tableau will generate the proper SQL to send to your specific database. Or in Oracle SQL, I believe you can add an interval data type to a date. Either way, that let's Oracle handle the leap year adjustments instead of your query.

Answer (score 0):

since you are subtracting the year from year 2000 which is a leap year, I will change your SQL to check if the difference between DELIVERY_DATE and TRADING_DATE is not divisible by 4; If not divisible by 4 (say 1999 which is not leap year and month is Feb-29 then use Feb 28, 1999).  This will only work if you fix the reference year to 2000 which is a leap year.  I can give you another answer if you change the reference year <> 2000.  Hope this helps.

```
 SELECT TO_DATE(
      CASE WHEN mod(extract(year from "DELIVERY_DATE") - extract(year from "TRADING_DATE"),4)!=0
            AND to_char("TRADING_DATE", 'mm/dd') = '02/29'
    then to_char(extract(year from TO_DATE('01/01/2000','DD/MM/YYYY')) - 
           extract(year from "DELIVERY_DATE") + 
           extract(year from "TRADING_DATE")) ||
           to_char("TRADING_DATE" - 1, 'mmdd')  
    else to_char(extract(year from TO_DATE('01/01/2000','DD/MM/YYYY')) - 
           extract(year from "DELIVERY_DATE") + 
           extract(year from "TRADING_DATE")) ||
           to_char("TRADING_DATE", 'mmdd') 
    END,'YYYYMMDD')  AS ANSWER 
    FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: The expression `to_char(extract(year from TO_DATE('01/01/2000','DD/MM/YYYY'))` can be replaced with a simple `'2000'` but it should actually be `2000` (a number not a string)